# How to properly calculate leveraged returns

Tags: returns, log-returns, leverage

Imagine we have a certain price movement, where the price starts at 1000 and ends at 1200, with some fluctuations in the middle. For the sake of the example, imagine it's hourly timestamps, and it's a *long* only strategy. I went ahead and calculated the simple and log returns, as well as the cumulative returns. As expected, the cumulative returns calculated for both the simple and log returns match.

| price | simple_returns | log_returns | cum_sum_simple | cum_sum_log |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 1100 | 0.10000 | 0.09531 | 1.10000 | 1.10000 |
| 900 | -0.18182 | -0.20067 | 0.90000 | 0.90000 |
| 800 | -0.11111 | -0.11778 | 0.80000 | 0.80000 |
| 950 | 0.18750 | 0.17185 | 0.95000 | 0.95000 |
| 1100 | 0.15789 | 0.14660 | 1.10000 | 1.10000 |
| 1500 | 0.36364 | 0.31015 | 1.50000 | 1.50000 |
| 1200 | -0.20000 | -0.22314 | 1.20000 | 1.20000 |

This outputs a return of `0.2` (20%), which is expected. `(1200 - 1000) / 1000` is also 20%.

Now imagine we introduce leverage into the equation, for example **2**. From my current understanding, in order to introduce the leverage into the returns, we have to multiply it by the simple returns, not the log returns. We can then calculate the cumulative sum as before. So it would be:

| price | lev_returns | cum_sum_lev |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | nan | nan |
| 1100 | 0.20000 | 1.20000 |
| 900 | -0.36364 | 0.76364 |
| 800 | -0.22222 | 0.59394 |
| 950 | 0.37500 | 0.81667 |
| 1100 | 0.31579 | 1.07456 |
| 1500 | 0.72727 | 1.85606 |
| 1200 | -0.40000 | 1.11364 |

This means that the final return would be `0.113`, or 11.3%. This in itself is already a little counter intuitive—as one would expect the gains to be double, so 40%—but this could in theory make sense since losses (with simple returns) are more amplified than the gains.

What is really confusing me, is that if we were to calculate the total final return independently of the path the price took to get there—so by taking only the last and first prices—, then:

`r = ((1200 - 1000) / 1000) * 2` 
`r = 0.4`

What am I missing here?

Comment: The results vary because It depends *how* you leverage: if you adjust every day so as to maintain a constant leverage of 2 (the way 2x ETF's operate) then it is 11.3%, if you establish a position with (initial) leverage of 2 and then stand back and don't do anything until you sell (and you survive without a margin call) then you get 40%. The difference is sometimes called the Volatility DRag effect of leveraged ETF's.

Comment: I see, that starts to make a little bit more sense in my head. I guess in my case the leverage readjusting would happen everytime a trade was closed, and a new position was opened. Do you know a book on this subject you'd recommend?

Comment: Just a note that, generally, leverage is not free. Make sure you consider the extra cost of borrowing capital to leverage your investment.

Comment: I did not learn this stuff from textbooks but years ago the SEC and CFTC forced me to take exams covering securities and futures brokerage operations. I studied from prep notes, test questions and by asking co-workers. So I can't recommend any books, but it should be relatively easy to find online material about how margin loans work, how futures work. With simple examples of calculations, no fancy maths required.